# How store birthdays with unknown year in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm a complete newbie with Outlook, and I thought I'd start easy by adding birthdays of friends to my calendar.  MS has [a tutorial on how to do this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keep-track-of-birthdays-and-anniversaries-RZ006082309.aspx), but it seems to assume you know the year of a person's birth, and in many cases, I don't.  Is there an easy way to say something like "January 2 is so-and-so's birthday" and have that information (in some form) appear on January 2 of any year I'm looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an event to your calendar with a yearly recurrence on the date of the birthday. You can set the options so there is no reminder and/or the time is shown as free.

[image]

[image]